# Prove that f is integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $(X,m)$ is a measure space with $m(X)<\infty$ Assume that 
$a=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} m\{x\in X: |f(x)|\geq n\}<\infty$, show that $\int_X |f(x)| dm \leq m(X)+a$
My thought is that we can separate $\int_X f dm=\int_{|f|\geq 1} |f(x)| dm +\int_{|f|<1} |f(x)| dm$, the second part is less than $m(X)$, but how do we show that the first part is less than $a$?
Thank you

Comment: Split the terms in the given sum for $a$ into terms of the form $A_n=m\{x:\in X:\ n+1> |f|\geq n\}$ and rearrange the repeated terms together. Notice that the same $A_n$ repeats $n$ times. Now, $nA_n\geq \int_{A_n}|f|$. Summing in $n$ you get $a\geq \int_{A_1+A_2+...}|f|=\int_{|f|\geq1}|f|$.

Comment: why $nA_n\geq \int_{A_n} |f|$? is it supposed to be $(n+1)A_n$?

Comment: Yes, it is $n+1$. Do you see the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}a&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}m\{x:\ |f|\geq n\}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}m\{x:\ k\leq|f|<k+1\}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)m\{x:\ n\leq|f|<n+1\}\\
&\geq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{\{x:\ n\leq|f|<n+1\}}|f|\\
&=\int_{}|f|
\end{align}

As you can see, we didn't need the $m(X)$ in the bound. But it is likely that in your problem the definition of $a$ was the sum starting at $n=1$. The term $m\{x:\ |f|\geq0\}$ is the $m(X)$.

Comment: Thank you! The summation is supposed to start at n=1